# Displaying whether the radio button selected in button_click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, radio-button

I would like to know like if a redio button selected a statement will be execute in the button_click event but i am not sure how can i do that. I want to be like this but it is not working.

```
    private void butto1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("radibutton1 selected");
            // execute other statement
        }

        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
             MessageBox.Show ("radibutton2 selected");
            // execute other statement
        }

    }
```

If i placed in radiobutton CheckChanged event it is working but i would like in button_Click event. I have find and research alot but still i cant find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put a line like below to check it it show? If it not then you don't set your button's click event to this function:

```
private void butto1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show ("Button Clicked!");

     // And this two line:
     MessageBox.Show(radioButton1.Checked.ToString()); // true or false?
     MessageBox.Show(radioButton2.Checked.ToString()); // true or false?
}
```

Comment: thanks yup it show.. but once i put this line inside the if (radioButton1.Checked == true) it does not shows.

Comment: sir so sorry for the late reply, my internet was not working.. so i have to wait... and call the customer service, they reset my connection thats y was late. i apologize for it. Sir i tried, the result was button clicked, then true, then false.

Comment: Then following code surely being run: `if (radioButton1.Checked) MessageBox.Show ("radibutton1 selected");`, it can not be other way. If you run this but don't show, no one on stackoverflow can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the radio buttons are in a group i.e. grouped in a panel then you can use a simple Linq statement to find the radio button which is checked.

```
var radioChecked = panel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

You can return a list of all checked radio buttons by simply

```
var radioCheckedList = yourForm.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(r => r.Checked).ToList(); 
foreach(var radio in radioCheckedList)
{
    if (radio.Name == "radio1")
    {
        // display something
    }

    else if (radio.Name == "radio2")
    {
        // display somnething
    }
}
```